How do I get sheet resistance from my hall sensor model? Do I just put in that formula? If so, how do I put 'ln' and 'pi' in?
How can I achieve sheet resistance in my hall sensor model? How do I input that formula in to get that output graph?
Any feedback helps, thank you.
I am referencing from this paper. https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/11/6/6284




Didn't you ask this same question a few days ago?

Please provide references for the bottom two images. Also, what's all this about? Is this schoolwork? Or something else? What, exactly? Include context detail.

@Andyaka Yes I did, but I had no valuable feedback and I'm still stuck.

@periblepsis It's for my own report writing, and I've included the paper I'm referencing from.

@Arl Thanks so much for the link. I'll have to read it if I want to be of any use. So thanks again for including the link. That said, I'm not sure if I will find the time here. Also, in addition to the link, were I to find the time to read the paper, I'd like very much for you to write a lot more about how you are reading that paper, what you get from it, where you don't follow the authors well, etc. Details, details, details. Write! It would save me so much time to listen to your mind as you read that paper. Hearing the resonances of another mind helps a lot.

@Arl - Hi, This is the 3rd related question you have asked. || As this is a slightly different question & formula to the one you asked & deleted two days ago, we won't require you to go back and edit that one. But please be aware that your question history is getting noticed. Try to avoid giving any impression that you are deleting & reposting unsuccessful questions, or close variations of them. People could have spent some time analysing those questions, and that time is potentially wasted if that question is deleted & the same one is asked and analysed again.

(continued) Please remember: To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, etc.) please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) as a minimum. But that's from a published paper, so you can also include the name of the paper, authors, publication etc. as well. Always add the reference to the best of your ability. || Please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules, as they differ from typical forums. TY

@SamGibson Thanks, noted. I'm new here and still trying to figure it out.

@periblepsis From what I know the paper is a graph comparison between dc biasing and sheet resistance. But in LTspice, only AC,DC and sweep analysis possible. So, I'm confused on how the author of this paper managed to obtain this output. I just started learning LTspice a few weeks ago as well.

@Arl If it is simply an LTspice issue, then I might be of help. However, I honestly can say that I may need to read the paper with understanding before I can do that. And that takes a substantial effort. If you already have put in that work and do understand it well, then I may need your help there. So that I can help with LTspice. Thanks so much for your response. Every little bit helps.

@periblepsis I'm trying to incorporate that formula into my circuit, but I'm not sure how 'ln' and 'pi' goes in into LTspice.

@Arl LTspice already understands pi as a special value. So you can just use 2*pi for example. It knows. It also knows the ln() function, as well. There is a special set of brackets, {}, that tells LTspice to evaluate what's inside that. So you may need to include those outside brackets to cause it to evaluate the expression inside them. Try that?

@periblepsis Oh I see, will try that. I hope it works. Thanks!
